# Regex: Getting input field with numeric validation to allow a leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have an input field as follows:

```
<label for="start_time">Agency total amount public   funding  </label>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKeyComma(event)" name="orgFundingTotal" id="orgFundingTotal" value="<?php echo isset($post->orgFundingTotal) ? $post->orgFundingTotal : set_value('orgFundingTotal'); ?>"  class="form-control"/>
<span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('orgFundingTotal');?>&nbsp;</span>
```

The input is not recognizing zero as a valid value.

Here is the validation rule:

```
function isNumberKeyComma(evt)
{
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
   caracter = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9 && !caracter.match(/^[0-9 ,]+$/)) 
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Is there any reason this validation would not accept a zero?

I know it's a problem with the regex line here:
    `if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9 && !caracter.match(/^[0-9 ,]+$/))`

Comment: @Sammitch - thanks, I updated the title.

Comment: I know the line in question is    if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9 && !caracter.match(/^[0-9 ,]+$/))  - I'm just not a regex expert!

Comment: What happens when you've replace `!caracter.match(/^[0-9 ,]+$/)` to `!caracter.match(/[^0-9 ,]+$/)`?

Comment: @eeya - no dice. Also, ran it through here, which said "any character NOT in 0-9" http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

Comment: Just to verify, You also want to 'exclude' 0 on keypress as well?